# Можно ли узнать из какого метода контроллера вызывается представление

Tags: c#, asp.net

Можно ли узнать из какого метода контроллера вызывается представление?

Comment: Вы можете передавать в представление информацию о методе контроллера. Через модель, через Viewbag/ViewData...как угодно в общем.

Answer (score 3):

В представлении можно воспользоваться `ViewContext`

```
<p> Controller - @ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller") </p> 
<p> Action - @ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action") </p>
```

Comment: Вопрос чуть в другом. В контроллере есть метод который возвращает представление. Я вызываю этот метод из этого же контроллера, но из другого метода.

Comment: Прошу прощенья). Там разницы нет. Спасибо за помощь.